# What have you done or what have you been doing to my dress?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Someone has borrowed a dress and returns it dirty and torn.

Is there any difference in nuance between: "what have you been doing to my dress?" or "what have you done to my dress?" Can they both be used in this situation?

To me "what have you been doing" is asking "what have you been doing to get the dress so dirty and torn" whereas "what have you done" expresses the fact that I'm angry my dress is ruined. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you're not correct. The continuous form is only really likely if the "damage" appears to have been caused by doing something *repeatedly* and/or for an *extended period of time*. Thus the continuous form is inherently somewhat more "accusatory", because phrasing it that way implies the speaker isn't expecting / won't accept any kind of response based on ***It was an accident*** (because "accidents" are normally one-off actions that don't persist for long).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In the example "Have you been urinating in the parking lot?" ( Have you been doing something you shouldn't have?) the continuous can be used for an on-off action that doesn't necessarily last long . I don't understand the difference. See: ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272380/

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but I think there's a *tendency* to use the continuous form when berating or accusing a *child*. Suppose I see that a bottle in my fridge door has toppled over and spilled - which I assume was caused by someone opening & closing the door carelessly. It seems to me I'm more likely to ask another *adult* the question *Did you open the fridge door?*, where I might ask a child *Have you been opening the fridge door?* (even though the activity isn't really "continuous" in either case).

Comment: ...maybe it's down to subconscious stereotyping, as in *naughty children are **always** being naughty*, whereas adults (who've grown up enough to have a moral code) would only be likely to make occasional slip-ups. I dunno.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers "opening and closing the door carelessly". Could that be once, opening and closing the door once?

Comment: Yes - just as *lighting a cigarette at the petrol station forecourt is very dangerous*  is true even if you only do it once

Comment: @ FumbleFingers But can you say: "Have you been lighting a cigarette at the petrol station' if it happened once? Can the continuous be used like this ?

Comment: The continuous isn't *likely* in that context, no. But to the extent that it *might* be used at all, it's more likely if the addressee is a child, and the speaker is effectively "scolding" them. But to be honest, this is such a fine nuance of usage that I'm not convinced it's worth trying to get a handle on it if you're not a native Anglophone in the first place. The *What have you been doing? / What have you done?* distinction (re *current relevance of past act*) is worth you learning, but not this one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just want to know why "what have you been doing to my dress?" needs duration and/or repetition and "Have you been peeing in the parking lot?" doesn't.  The first sentence is some kind of scolding as well.

Answer (score 1):

The nuance is about time, and whether the damage has *already been done* or is *continuing*.

> "what have you been doing to my dress?"

Suggests the damage is ongoing and will continue – appropriate if they are still wearing the dress.

> "what have you done to my dress?"

Suggests the damage already happened – appropriate if the dress is returned in poor condition.

These are only nuances, and both versions could be used interchangeably.